# upgrade : spring framework 5.2.X

Tags: spring

I want to upgrade spring framework from 4 to 5. Should i go with latest version such as 5.2.6 or any prior version i.e 5.2.0 or 5.2.4 etc? How should i decide on this ? I don't have any specific feature in mind.Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see any reason not going for the latest.

Usually the major releases (from 4 to 5) might break something, so you might want to wait if it requires a lot of changes on your side, but if you're going to move to 5.2.x - go for the latest